# Sticky header doesn't scroll all the way back up (overlaps div below)

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I have an issue with my sticky header: it behaves properly when I scroll down but when I scroll all the way back up it doesn't go back to its starting position, instead it seems to overlap the div below. I really don't understand where the problem comes from so any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Here's the code:

```js
        
// When the user scrolls the page, execute myFunction 
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

// Get the header
var header = document.getElementById("myHeader");

// Get the offset position of the navbar
var sticky = header.offsetTop;

// Add the sticky class to the header when you reach its scroll position. Remove "sticky" when you leave the scroll position
function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky)
  {
    header.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    header.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

```css
.header {
  padding: 10px 16px;
  background: #1919ff;
  color: #f1f1f1;
}
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#about {
  background-color: #ccccff;
  height: 400px;
  width: 67%;
  margin: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.round-border{
   border-radius: 50%;
  }
.portrait-image{
    width: 25%;    
  }
.header-bar{
    height: 4px;
    width: 80%;
    background: #272C31;
    margin-left: 20%;
    margin-top: 3%;
}

#image-position {
  float: right;
  margin: 8% 6% 0 0;
}
#text {
  float: left;
  text-align: right;
  width: 57%;
  word-break: break-all;
  margin-top: 11%;
  margin-left: 7%;
}

p.medium {
    font-size:135%;
    line-height: 1.5;
}

.clearfix {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style type="text/css"> .icon {background:none;} </style>

<body style="background-color: #5D6D7E;">
  <div class="header" id="myHeader">
    <h2>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;xxxxxxxxx</h2>
  </div>
  <div id="about" class="clearfix">
    <div id="text">
      <p class="medium">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx<br/>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</p>
      <br/>
      <div class="header-bar"></div>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <h4 style="font-size:150%;">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</h4>
    </div>
    <img class="portrait-image round-border" id="image-position" src="http://abload.de/img/gpuxh.png" alt="portrait">
  </div>
  
</body>
```

Comment: consider removing code which does not contribute to the issue - for example the extra CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition should be tested as `window.pageYOffset > sticky` instead of `window.pageYOffset >= sticky` inside the window scroll function...

https://www.codeply.com/go/Qm2vXNiCvh

```js
        
// When the user scrolls the page, execute myFunction 
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

// Get the header
var header = document.getElementById("myHeader");

// Add the sticky class to the header when you reach its scroll position. Remove "sticky" when you leave the scroll position
function myFunction() {
  // Get the offset position of the navbar
  var sticky = header.offsetTop;

  if (window.pageYOffset > sticky)
  {
    header.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    header.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

```css
.header {
  padding: 10px 16px;
  background: #1919ff;
  color: #f1f1f1;
}
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#about {
  background-color: #ccccff;
  height: 400px;
  width: 67%;
  margin: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.round-border{
   border-radius: 50%;
  }
.portrait-image{
    width: 25%;    
  }
.header-bar{
    height: 4px;
    width: 80%;
    background: #272C31;
    margin-left: 20%;
    margin-top: 3%;
}

#image-position {
  float: right;
  margin: 8% 6% 0 0;
}
#text {
  float: left;
  text-align: right;
  width: 57%;
  word-break: break-all;
  margin-top: 11%;
  margin-left: 7%;
}

p.medium {
    font-size:135%;
    line-height: 1.5;
}

.clearfix {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style type="text/css"> .icon {background:none;} </style>

<body style="background-color: #5D6D7E;">
  <div class="header" id="myHeader">
    <h2>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;xxxxxxxxx</h2>
  </div>
  <div id="about" class="clearfix">
    <div id="text">
      <p class="medium">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx<br/>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</p>
      <br/>
      <div class="header-bar"></div>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <h4 style="font-size:150%;">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</h4>
    </div>
    <img class="portrait-image round-border" id="image-position" src="http://abload.de/img/gpuxh.png" alt="portrait">
  </div>
  
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it and it fixed the overlap but it jumps abruptly when you scroll up. Is there anyway to make it smooth?

Comment: You could use `position: sticky` instead.

Comment: Thanks it's perfect now!